# Using a c library from python (undefined reference)

Tags: python, c, linker

I don't know a whole lot about linking in C, and I'm having an issue. My code is in Python, but I am trying to use a library in C (libnfc, specifically). My python code calls a function from IOLib.py, which looks like this:

```
    from ctypes import cdll
    lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./jk4Lib.so')

    def getRFID():
        return lib.NFCPollWrapper()
```

jk4Lib.so is a shared library in the same folder, compiled from a c program

jk4RFIDPoll.c:

```
    #include "jk4RFIDPoll.h"
    static void stop_polling(int sig){
         //code
    }

    extern int NFCPollWrapper() {
         //code
    }
```

jk4RFIDPoll.h:

```
    #ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
    #  include "config.h"
    #endif // HAVE_CONFIG_H

    #include "libnfc-1.7.0/include/nfc/nfc.h"
    #include "libnfc-1.7.0/include/nfc/nfc-types.h"

    #include "libnfc-1.7.0/utils/nfc-utils.h"
```

libnfc-1.7.0 is a folder inside my programs main directory.
This is compiled with the following lines:

```
    gcc -c -Wall -fpic jk4RFIDPoll.c

    gcc -shared -o libjk4.so jk4RFIDPoll.o
```

This all compiles fine, but then when I run the python program, I get undefined references to all the function calls in jk4RFIDPoll.so. I know the functions are in the headers I included, but I think it's not properly linking everything.

I'm guessing I'm not doing enough at compilation or something. The OS is a version of Debian. I should add that I have been able to run the example programs in the libnfc folder. Let me know if there is any other info I should provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get undefined references, because the dynamic linker doesn't know how to resolve them.
For this to work, you must add the necessary libraries when linking your shared object

```
gcc -shared -o libjk4.so jk4RFIDPoll.o -lnfc
```

Comment: I tried this, and it still gives the same undefined reference. I confirmed that libnfc is a library on my machine by using: `/sbin/ldconfig -p`, and finding libnfc.so. I also changed the first two includes to `#include <nfc/nfc.h>` and `#include <nfc/nfc-types.h>` so they looked for the library files instead of the local files.

Comment: Well after trying it again, it worked. Not 100% sure what changed, I think maybe I had to add /usr/local/lib to the path, then compile the .so again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not creating the shared library correctly.  Try something like:

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libjk4.so.1 -o libjk4.so.1.0.1 jk4RFIDPoll.o
```

After compiling, install the shared library someplace (e.g., /usr/local/lib/) before using it.  If you don't use ldconfig, then don't forget to update your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to include the install path.

Check out http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html for more details on how to compile and install shared libraries on Linux.

When you load it from Python, you should specify the soname, not the actual path to the .so file.